# Macro inside a Function and stringfication

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I have the following function `foo()` and the macro `FOO(str)`.

```
void foo(const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args,fmt);
   vsprintf(msgbuff,fmt,args);
   va_end(args);
   printf("%s\n",msgbuff);
}

#define FOO(str)\
foo str;           // No need of brackets as they are coming in 'str'
```

I used to call the macro like below:

```
FOO(("My %s is %s\n","Name","Bala"));
```

Now my Requirement is:

Macro `FOO(str)` should not call my function `foo()` directly but instead it should call it through another function like `func()`.

Finally my macro should be like below

```
#define FOO(str)\
func(#str) // Do I need to Stringizing str?
```

My question is, how can I call function `foo()` from inside `func()`?
Please suggest any possible implementation.

Comment: Sounds like you need a variadic macro.

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro at all? Never use a macro when a function will do the job as well! And the first version of the macro is missleading and obfuscates your code.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `func()`.

Comment: Hi olaf , iam changing only the internal implementation of macro in my existing project.  so i cannot change the macro usage . i can only change its implentation

Comment: Hi kampling ,just for example i have said func(). actually i need to know how to call foo() inside func()

Comment: This appears too abstract to suggest a solution.  _Generally_ speaking, func needs to be variadic since your usage (via `FOO` calls) suggests calling with an indeterminate, typed tuple.  But then, func could just use ordinary variadic semantics to chunk its stuff into some buffer, then... do whatever unmentioned thing makes you say you're _required_ to call func to do.  However, your _foo_ isn't doing much more than chunking stuff into a buffer itself... something `func` could easily do without bothering foo, which just leads to the question... what is your _real_ question?

Comment: @HWalters: Could be a typical [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hello , Don't take it as a XY Problem .

Comment: Hello , Don't take it as a XY Problem :) . Iam working on a legacy project . It already have macros implented like above. Now I cannot change the Macro syntax { #define FOO(str) } as the same macro is used by many other developers. I only have the option to change the internal implementation of FOO. And FOO should call a function func() inside which i can use foo() . Now the issue is I dont know how to pass the 'str' given to macro as argument to foo() [foo() inside func()] ????

Comment: "I cannot change the Macro syntax" ...this implies that `func` should be variadic.  How do you write a variadic function?  Just like `foo` is written; so that should be no mystery.  So what's left... how to call foo?  Apparently foo just takes a format string and its arguments; so `foo("%s", my_buffer);` will work nicely.  How do you build such a buffer?  Just like `foo` does; so that shouldn't be a mystery either.  But once you have such a buffer, why do you need to call foo?  Why not just `printf("%s\n", my_buffer);`? ...

Comment: @H Walters . Absolutely agree with your point & I can use same foo() like variadic func() . Assume if Macro(with two more args other than str) is like this #define FOO(appid , num , str) E.g: FOO(15,25,("My %s is %s\n","name","bala")) . How can i edit function foo() for this , so that i can print 15 ,25 , str seperately using printf.

Comment: @Balaganesh.V I'm confused... your question said nothing about changing your call sites; it only said you want to change `FOO`, currently called a certain way, from calling _foo_ directly to calling _foo_ via a new _func_.  What you're describing _now_ requires changing your existing calls to `FOO`.

Comment: ...thinking it over, I now suspect this could be part of your question.  If so, could you edit your question?  At a minimum, something like "`FOO` will change to support additional parameters, but must also support the varying parameters to the original `FOO`" (though I'm _still_ not sure why you have to change `FOO` as opposed to just creating a new macro `FUNC`).  FYI, my goal here is just to get a question I (or someone else) can post an answer to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use variadic macro

```
#define FOO(...) \
fun(__VA_ARGS__);
```

And call it like this

```
FOO("A", "B", "C")
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by Olaf, this is not encouraged and can be replaced by a direct function call

Comment: The question does not say anything about using a variable number of arguments. And even if, as given a macro is not necessary, hence strongly discouraged.

Comment: @lapinozz: He tagged his question with C and not C++.

Comment: Right, foolish me

Comment: I did no way point out macros are useless (or almost useless). And the main issue still applies: There are no variable arguments.

Comment: Hi the problem is i can use the macro only like this - FOO(("My %s is %s\n","Name","Bala"));   ....  I need to call foo()  from a functio func().